# WPS Office determines screen resolution incorrectly

Tags: resolution, wps-office

I'm trying out [WPS Office](http://wps-community.org/) (version Alpha21 10.1.0.5672~a21). The first issue I'm running into is a display bug: the display is compressed horizontally (or elongated vertically, whichever). Only the document display is affected, the user interface part is fine.

This isn't a font issue: I see this with every font, and with figures. In the screenshot below, the blue rectangle is in fact a 1cm×1cm square, and the PDF output is correct.

[image: screenshot]

On startup, WPS Office shows a “System Check” window which mentions

> System DPI is asymmetric. WPS Office may have display issues.

The “solution” link leads to http://community.wps.cn/wiki/dpix_not_equal_dpiy which is a broken link. If the solution exists anywhere on the web now, I can't find it (possibly because it's in Chinese only).

`xrandr` output (that's actually 158dpi both horizontally and vertically, so whatever WPS Office is doing to determine the resolution, it's mistaken):

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
```

I use Sawfish without a destkop environment. [Fouad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/247050/fouad) reports that he has the same issue under XFCE, but not under Cinnamon.

How can I make WPS Office display document content at a correct aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

WPS is a proprietary solution, it does not offer support or configuration or debugging options to know exactly why it gives this type of messages, nor does it have open documentation to know how to provide solutions. In any case, it can be read that WPS is not capable of handling the current pixel density of the device, but the reason is unknown.